# Ruby code refactoring

Tags: ruby

I have n-times similar statements

```
    if trigger_data.tt_closed
      unless trouble_ticket.changes.key?(:status)
        @run = 0
        break
      end
      unless trouble_ticket.changes[:status][1] == "Closed"
        @run = 0
        break
      end
    end

    if trigger_data.tt_assignee
      unless trouble_ticket.changes.key?(:assigned_to)
        @run = 0
        break
      end
      unless trouble_ticket.changes[:assigned_to][1] == trigger_data.tt_assignee
        @run
        break
      end
    end
```

How to refactoring that code? Maybe dynamic statement build with pass some hash to input. I'm newbie in metaprogramming. Give me advise please

Comment: Did you forget @run = 0 in the final one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you inside a loop? Here is a possible way of doing it

```
def check(td, tt, trigger, key, ticket_changes)
    if td.send(trigger)
      unless tt.changes.key?(key)
        @run = 0
        return true
      end
      unless tt.changes[key][1] == ticket_changes
        @run = 0
        return true
      end
    end
    return false
end

def metacheck(td, tt)
    [[:tt_closed, :status, "Closed"],
     [:tt_assignee, :assigned_to, td.tt_assignee]].each do |k|
        return if check(td, tt, k[0], k[1], k[2])
     end
end


metacheck(trigger_data, trouble_ticket)
```

I have used an array of triplets to check the conditions.
The check can further be simplified as

```
def check(td, tt, trigger, key, ticket_changes)
    return false unless td.send(trigger)
    if !tt.changes.key?(key) or (tt.changes[key][1] != ticket_changes)
        @run = 0
        return true
    end
    return false
end
```

We can join all the conditions together. But I think this captures the original intension best.